# Execute sql file in Exception statement

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, plsql

Hi I'm trying to execute an SQL File in a Exception Statement when I'm executing an Spool file.

I have something like this:

```
column dt new_value _dt 
select to_char(sysdate,'yyyymmdd_hh24mi') dt from dual; 
set line 10000;
set pagesize 50000;
set serveroutput on;

spool .\backup\backup.sql

select dbms_metadata.get_ddl(object_type, object_name)
from user_objects
where object_type in ('FUNCTION')
and object_name = 'TEST_TABLE';

Spool Off

spool .\!Run_&_dt..txt

BEGIN
    raise_application_error( -20001, 'This is a custom error' );
EXCEPTION 
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        Prompt ./backup/backup.sql
        @ ./backup/backup.sql
END;

Spool Off
```

And I get the next error:

```
>> BEGIN
     raise_application_error( -20001, 'This is a custom error' );
EXCEPTION 
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        Prompt ./backup/backup.sql
        @ ./backup/backup.sql
END;


Spool Off
Error at line 18
ORA-06550: line 6, column 11:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "/" when expecting one of the following:

    <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>
    current delete exists prior
ORA-06550: line 6, column 49:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SQL" when expecting one of the following:

    <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>
    current delete exists prior
```

I don't have any idea, thanks in advance.

Best regards.

Comment: You are mixing PL/SQL commands with SQL*Plus commands.  That is why it doesn't work.

Comment: The question is really: what exactly are you trying to achieve ? What actual business problem are you trying to solve ? As others have said, you are mixing up all sorts of concepts here. In particular: PL/SQL runs in the database. It cannot possibly call back to any script that happens to exist on your desktop. Also I don't see the point of a PL/SQL block that does nothing but raising an exception just to catch it.

Comment: I want to back up the scripts of some database objects and then execute the updated scripts, if these fail the backups must be executed in the exception statement. I usually use the spool command to do the backups, but I want to improve the restoration process in case of failure.

Comment: Is there a workaround?

Comment: Work around: Use a Code Repository.

Answer (score 5):

So it's a bit confusing - you're writing a SQL*Plus script, which accepts both SQL*Plus commands as well as SQL commands and PL/SQL blocks.

[SQL*Plus commands](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQPUG/ch_twelve001.htm#SQPUG023) are executed locally on your client machine, so they have access to other scripts on your local filesystem.

Everything inside a `BEGIN..END` block is **PL/SQL code**, and it'll behave differently than the rest of your script because it's a different language. The entire block of code is sent to the server and executed there, and the database doesn't know how to interpret sqlplus commands like `prompt` and `@`.

There are ways to have a PL/SQL block execute scripts *on the database server* - [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8836734/3061852) for more details - but I don't think that's really what you want.

It's hard to tell what you want from your example, but I'd suggest looking into [handling sqlplus errors using a shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14734131/managing-error-handling-while-running-sqlplus-from-shell-scripts) - split this into two sqlplus scripts, then run the first script, check the return code, and if you got an error, run your second script. Sqlplus itself doesn't really have much in the way of built-in exception handling.

Comment: I want to back up the scripts of some database objects and then execute the updated scripts, if these fail the backups must be executed in the exception statement.                                                                                                                   I usually use the spool command to do the backups, but I want to improve the restoration process in case of failure.

Answer (score 3):

## Answer to posted question

kfinity's answer is pretty good.  If you want to run a script based on pass/fail, you will need to catch the exception at the Shell level and run the next script accordingly.

## Answer based on your "what you are trying to do"

As I read your comments, I feel you are trying to do the following

1. Install new objects
2. If that fails, reinstall old objects.

You don't need to "backup old objects".  You just need to install the new objects in such a way that they are not in the current `EDITION` of the database.

[`Edition-Based Redefinition`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e41502/adfns_editions.htm#ADFNS020) is a feature of Oracle 11gR2 and higher.  It allows you to "install but not use by default" certain database objects.

Your script process would go like this

1. Create new `EDITION`
2. set session to new `EDITION`
3. install objects in new `EDITION`
4. If everything passes, make that `EDITION` the current edition
5. If something goes wrong.  Drop that `EDITION`.

   - Old objects aren't changed.
   - Backups of DDLs are no longer needed.

Usage example is also available here: https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/edition-based-redefinition-11gr2